# How to get the last modified date of a google sheet as getLastUpdated file property not apt for this purpose

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to get the last modified date of a google sheet using sheetID. I used the file property getLastUpdated() but it is not giving me the last saved date of a googlesheet. Below is the code I used:

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var curFile = DriveApp.getFileById(FILEID);
var lastUpdated = curFile.getLastUpdated();
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: I think that `getLastUpdated()` returns the last updated date as a Date object. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getlastupdated) But from `it is not giving me the last saved date of a googlesheet`, in order to correctly understand about your goal, can I ask you about the current value and the output value you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Working Snippet

```js
function getLastModifiedDate() {
  let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let id = sh.getId();
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  let date = file.getLastUpdated();

  Logger.log(date)
  
}
```

This gives output:

```sh
Mon Jan 25 05:35:27 GMT-05:00 2021
```

This script is bound to a spreadsheet, i.e.:

- You create a new spreadsheet
- Go to the menu > tools > script editor.
- Paste this code
- Modify the Sheet
- Run code

---

The only thing I could really see wrong with your code is the fact that the `FILE_ID` is not referenced, but it may be higher in your script but you haven't pasted it here. If not, then the only thing you were missing is getting the ID form the active spreadsheet.

#### References

- [getId of SS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getid)
- [getLastUpdated](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getLastUpdated())
- [getFileById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)

Comment: It works. But, the below code does not. Can't understand why :         var fileId= sheetUrl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
      var lastUpdated = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getLastUpdated();
      Logger.Log(lastUpdated);